# How to read the text file using LINQ with specified line number

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a text file. I need to find the total count of line numbers which starts with "3" and the total count is already available in the file which is available in the position line starts with "7200" - Position starts with 05 and length is 6. Similar way. Total amount also available in the line starts with "7200" - Position starts with 21 and length is 12.

[image: .txt File Data]

```
211 87236486287346872837468724682871238483XYZ BANK             
1200ABCDEF                               8128361287AXTAKJ COLL
3270210000893281012870095628   00002500     8981273687jhgsjhdg

3270210000896281712870095628   00002500     1231273687jhgajhdj

3270210000891286712870095628   00002500     4561273687cxvnmbal

3270210000899283612870095628   00002500     7891273687nmkdkjhk

720000000400021000080000000100000000000000008128361287        
9000001000001000000010002100008000000010000000000000000
```

For example : in my file total count of line starts with 3 is available in line starts with "7" i.e.  "000004"

Total amount is in line starts with "7" i.e. "000000010000"

Currently I am using my below c# code to loop the entire file and navigate to line starts with 7 and read the values which are available in the above mentioned positions, but is taking too much of time due to file records count might be too big like 200K

```
foreach (var line in FileLines)
{
    //// If line length is zero, then do nothing
    if (line.Length == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    switch (line.Substring(1, 1))
    {
        case 7:
            totalCount = int.Parse(line.Substring(4, 6));
            TotalAmount = line.Substring(20, 12);
            break;

        default:
            throw new Exception;
    }
}
```

is there any way I can able to rewrite my code using LINQ, so that I get little better performance?

Comment: What is too much time?  Should take less the a couple of seconds.  If it is taking longer than you probably have other issues like machine doesn't have enough memory.  Or you hard drive is fragmented.  linq will not run faster.  Probably slower.

Comment: Thank you for the response, so in that case my above code is better ? is their any way I can make little better in rewriting the same code in terms of performance

Comment: Once you find line exit for loop so you do not read entire file.

Comment: Generally using LINQ is slower or at least not faster that equivalent non-LINQ code... So trying to use LINQ to gain performance if very strange request. Some clarifications on your actual goals would help.

Comment: Good point. unfortunately the line which I am looking , line starts with "7" it is in the footer section of the File, so the line number starts with "7" is available at the end of the File. as explained in my example. so I have to loop all the lines which are available in the file might be 200k lines some time

Comment: Thank you Alexei Levenkov for the response. There is no requirement to use LINQ, just I need to rewrite my above mentioned code for better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Linq statement. What would make this more efficient is that it uses `Reverse` since you mention that the information you're looking for is in the footer.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),
        "TextFile.txt");
    try
    {
        var count =
            int.Parse(
            File.ReadAllLines(path)
            .Reverse()
            .First(line => line.Any() && (line.First() == '7'))
            .Substring(4, 6));
        Console.WriteLine($"Count = {count}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[image: console output]

**EDIT**

You have asked a great question about the performance. The great thing is that we don't have to speculate or guess! There is *always* a way to measure performance.

Here's the benchmark I just put together. And look, I did it really quickly so if anyone spots something I missed please point it out. But here's what I get:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),
        "TextFile.txt");
    try
    {
        // 200K lines of random guids
        List<string> builder = 
            Enumerable.Range(0, 200000)
            .Select(n => $"{{{System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}}}")
            .ToList();

        var footer =
            File.ReadAllLines(path);

        builder.AddRange(footer);

        var FileLines = builder.ToArray();

        var benchmark = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        benchmark.Start();
        int totalCount = int.MinValue;
        foreach (var line in FileLines)
        {
            //// If line length is zero, then do nothing
            if (line.Length == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            // Original code from post
            // switch (line.Substring(1, 1))
            // Should be:
            switch (line.Substring(0, 1))
            {
                case "7":
                    totalCount = int.Parse(line.Substring(4, 6));
                    // This is another issue!! Breaking from the switch DOESN'T break from the loop
                    break;
                    // SHOULD BE: goto breakFromInner;
                    // One of the few good reasons to use a goto statement!!
            }
        }
        benchmark.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"200K lines using Original code: Elapsed = {benchmark.Elapsed}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Count = {totalCount}");


        benchmark.Restart();
        for (int i = FileLines.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var line = FileLines[i];
            //// If line length is zero, then do nothing
            if (line.Length == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            // Original code from post
            // switch (line.Substring(1, 1))
            // Should be:
            switch (line.Substring(0, 1))
            {
                case "7":
                    totalCount = int.Parse(line.Substring(4, 6));
                    // One of the few good reasons to use a goto statement!!
                    goto breakFromInner;
            }
        }
        // See note
        breakFromInner:
        benchmark.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"200K lines using Original code with reverse: Elapsed = {benchmark.Elapsed}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Count = {totalCount}");

        benchmark.Restart();
        var count =
            int.Parse(
                FileLines
                .Reverse()
                .First(line => line.Any() && (line.First() == '7'))
                .Substring(4, 6));
        benchmark.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"200K lines using Linq with Reverse: Elapsed = {benchmark.Elapsed}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Count = {count}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[image: console output]

Comment: Thank you so much, one question performance wise can you confirm my code is better or your code (using LINQ) is better ?

Comment: You could do something similar, that is starting from the bottom, if you said `for (int i = lines.Length-1; i >= 0; i--){ ... }` instead.

Comment: For sure! I think the question you just asked in your comment is a great one. I'm working on a benchmark because I am curious about the same thing. BRB with that.

Comment: S based on your recent post, you have proved that LINQ with reverse will take less time then C# for each function. But as you have seen my initial post - I need to extract 2 values from line starts with "7", i.e. count and amount Position starts with 21 and length is 12. So based on your suggestion with LINQ reverse I need to write same LINQ query 2 times correct ? one for to get the count and other one for to get the amount . is my understanding is right ? If so then don't you think it may take little slower

Comment: Maybe! I'm still double checking my code to make sure I haven't made any big errors, but you see my main point, yes? If we're wondering about the performance of something, then let's figure out how we could measure it :)

Comment: Ah! Found error in original code! `switch (line.Substring(1, 1))` should be `switch (line.Substring(0, 1))`. This changes the result. Watch for new edit. Having way too much fun.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/line-starts-with-seven.git) this benchmark. PLEASE double-check my result! But it looks like Linq is more than a hundred times slower than iterating the list in code as long as you start from the bottom.

Comment: @IVSoftware - be careful, your benchmark may not be as clear cut as it seems (although the general gist of it feels right). Benchmarking is not easy, and there are a lot of mistakes one can make: https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/

Comment: @IVSoftware - Thank you again for your time, the link "Clone" which you have mentioned is not working. so the final conclusion is to use the my original code with reverse flow instead of LINQ right ?

Comment: Oops...I thought I had it set to **Public** visibility but it is now. Thanks for letting me know and plz try again.

Comment: As for the conclusion, using a sample array of ~200K lines, the `Linq` using the `Reverse` seems to run a _few_ times faster than the original code, but the optimized original code using the reverse strategy seems to run _hundreds_ of times faster than the other two.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, is there any alternative to “GoTo” statement , I read in google , we should avoid this statement. And also as per the dotnet diagnostic tool which is integrated in my company – we should not be using “goTo “ statement. Any other control flow recommendations.

Comment: Your original post is about loops, performance and Linq, so discussing `goto` would not only take us off-topic for this thread, if might be off-topic for SO in general because it would be more a matter of opinion rather than fact. Going into my 45th year of coding, I know all about the alternatives in this specific instance, and the code you see is the best code I know how to write :)